# Ensure a Typescript array has a specific value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm building a dropdown-style component the value and options are distinct props.
I'm hoping to use Typescript to ensure that the value is a valid option. While I could do this check at runtime, I feel like this is something I should be able to do in TS.

Is this possible?

```js
interface Props<N extends number> {
    count: N,
    options: Array<N | number> // Tuples don't work here, since this can be any length
}

const Component = <N extends number>({count, options} : Props<N>) => {
  // We could do a runtime check to verify that `count` is in `options`, but I'd rather do the check earlier if possible
}

Component({count: 5, options: [1,2,3]}) // This should be an error
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is inexpressible. Type systems can't solve everything. Your API seems a bit strange anyway. I think the core problem is that you have 2 independent parameters that are implicitly related. Why not make the first array element the "primary" option, and do away with count altogether?

Comment: Would [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Na4G9w) fit your needs?

Comment: @TobiasS. That seems to work. I tried something similar, but didn’t know what to put after the ternary check. What’s that spread notation on `[…O]`? I’ve never seen that before

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to infer both the literal types of `count` and `options` into the generic types `N` and `O`. This is trivial for `N`, but for `O` we need to hint to the compiler to infer a tuple type of number literals instead of just `number[]`. We can achieve this by wrapping `O` into a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) which looks like `[...O]`.

To achieve the validation, we can use a *conditional type* to check if `N` is a member of `O[number]`. If it is not a member, the conditional resolves to `never` leading to the error as nothing can be assigned to `never`.

```
interface Props<N extends number, O extends readonly number[]> {
  count: N;
  options: N extends O[number] ? readonly [...O] : never;
}
const Component = <N extends number, O extends readonly number[]>({
  count,
  options,
}: Props<N, O>) => {};
```

This works fine, as long as the array passed as `options` is a tuple type.

```
Component({ count: 5, options: [1, 2, 3] }); // error

Component({ count: 5, options: [1, 2, 3, 5] }); // ok

Component({ count: 5, options: [] as number[] }); 
// ok, all the elements in options are number and 5 does extend number :/
```

If `options` is an array type, its elements are of type `number` and `5` does extend `number` which ultimately passes the type checking.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOAeAOWQgA9IQATHZEAVwFsAjaAGmQHliyJLqoI4FDCAA2ATxoNmUANoBdAHzIA3gChkyBBlrgAXMgIBudcmxhgwnPqKlyVDjLpNoc5AH5k-QcPHIZAOkD2V30QCAA3aGMAX1UtEBwwZABhDHosYR4kgF5kQi47aidpNk5bHnsvIVEJYuh5BQAKNQ0tHTAWEzMLBM7o-XRsfAJShQBKZGylZWjjVXnU9MzwZs1tPWQAVjZuy30ZAEY2ACY2AGZXaLHDZAB6W+IoTCgFtIywleU19v1t0yxzHs-EdkKdkGc2JtLtc7g8MABrV5LD5gVZtDZ-XYJfauOBFKT1aE3VT3UzwthwEQiZBgAAWKAgIgg9Cy1FA-0BCWQcH4kmcUG5lC2yCEEGo5SFdQFuluqiAA0BCWQcH4kmcUG5lC2yCEEGo5SFdQFuluqiAA)